# Java: ConcurrentLinkedQueue behavior in a stream where certain elements are remove

Tags: java, java-8

If I have a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, is it safe to use stream to remove certain elements from the same list?

For example:

```
Queue<MyThread> threadList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyThread>();
//concurrently add and execute some threads to this list

//then we call this concurrently to remove done threads from the thread list
threadList.stream().filter( MyThread::isDone ).forEach( threadList::remove );
```

Comment: You could write it: `threadList.removeIf(MyThread::isDone)` (your version could throw a CME with non-concurrent collections)

Comment: I didn't saw that it has that method now. Thanks for the tip